# Mahout 0.9 CVB document topic mapping error

Tags: java, hadoop, cluster-analysis, mahout

I am trying to do the topics analysis on set of documents using the latest version of Mahout.

The output for topic to term mapping is proper with each topic having list of terms with corresponding probabilities.

But the when I tried getting the document to topic mapping , it only displays a set of topics starting with some letter. Like in this case all topics starting with letter a

Following is the sample code used to generate the document topic mapping:

```
VectorDumper.main(new String[] 
            { 
            "-i" , inputDocTopicsDir 
            , "-o", oututDocTopicsDir 
            , "-d", inputDictionaryDir 
            , "-dt", "sequencefile" 
            , "-sort", "true" 
            , "-vs", "10" });
```

**Sample output:** 
{2d:0.019996671414880783,3d:0.019994853350969108,4d:0.02000171234917903,5d:0.019994290328033588,a.config:0.01999309367417373,a.k.a:0.02000227944902019,a.system:0.01999771644223781,aaa:0.020003361639812457,aam:0.019990182999365072,aapm:0.020012465032122083,aapv:0.01999879522431889,aar:0.019995543474585993,aas:0.019995157547471696,aav:0.02000267326012652,ab:0.020025978185034182,aba:0.01999553819903237,abandon:0.020013355238553677,abandoned:0.01999559962237951,abandonment:0.019994194616256,abandons:0.02001433184497984,abatement:0.01997728075793184,abberationa:0.020001189392395737}

Answer (score 0):

These are **word vectors**, not topics. Topic modeling is a different domain than clustering.

K-means clustering (which you probably are using) will give you *average word counts*, not what one would intutively accept as "topics". No k-means ever will give you the result "american football" as a topic. It cannot. Use supervised techniques for that.

You probably truncated the word vectors somehow, and it gives you only the alphabetically first words.

Since every value is close to 0.02, your results may have degenerated to a near-random mess.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response.
I am using the CVB topic modelling algorithm. Am also quite surprise with the behavior in the code as i had followed the steps provided for it in various forums. Is it like i shouldn't use dictionary while printing the doc topic mapping? 
I can share the code if you want to have a look at it to correct it. Thanks